# Reset iPhone and can’t get it to unlock

Tags: iphone, icloud, apple-id

So for christmas one year my younger sister got an iPhone 5s. But currently she had to replace the battery and she had to reset her iPhone to do so.
She doesn't remember who set up all her iCloud and Apple ID information, so now we are stuck with a reset iPhone on the activation lock page. Someone please tell me how to fix this or if it even is fixable.

Comment: What does the activation lock screen say, does it give a hint as to the email address?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to recover your Apple ID [here](https://iforgot.apple.com/) . It’s the only one legal way.